# How to segment curved roads/lanes/paths/tracks/objects etc?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Is there anyway of segmenting detecting tracks just like in below image using image processing techniques?

Figure 1: Tracks of wheels on sand
[image]

Figure 2: One example of a track to be detected
[image]

Comment: even for a human that track is hard to see. Even if you could segment the track pixels I think it will be hard to extract the track because of all the intersections. From my intuition I would guess this is currently not solvable well.

Comment: What if there exist only one track(drawn in blue) at each frame not the intersections and crowd of other tracks. Is it possible to only follow one track segment in that situation?

Comment: segmenting the track pixels, maybe you can mention how to do that?

Comment: The problem will be with tracking the entire track-path. With the intensity varying across different images, it will be hard to find a one size fits all solution. Another problem is the tail of the track, which i think is extremely hard to detect. I would suggest you to look into a Deep Learning Solution (Try https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/). If you have enough data(if not use Transfer Learning) and the time to label them. Cheers.

Comment: @Merlin I think even segmenting the track pixels is very challenging for such images. You could try gradient extraction like SOBEL operator combined with some clustering or local normalization and the result in combination with some masking from color clustering (to distinguish sand from sea/shore/parasols and other stuff that leads to edges/gradients). But really, this looks very challenging to me.

Comment: another approach for extracting the track pixels (with directions) could be using a GABOR filter bank. Then you can compute some kind of probability for each edge direction. This could help in distinguishing overlapping tracks.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the answer is no. First I removed the illumination effect then apply Canny to get the features of the image, only a partial track is visible. Next, I performed colored segmentation to get the binary mask. Then I used a binary-mask to remove the background, again the only partial track is visible.

---

- 1. **Removing the illumination effect**: To make the track more visible, we need to reduce the lightning in the image. To reduce, we will smooth the image using [`cv2.GaussianBlur`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html) then we make the pixel evenly distribute within scale using [`cv2.divide`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d2c/group__core__hal__interface__divide.html).

  - [image]
  - ```py
    # Load the image
    img = cv2.imread("v1uU4.jpg")

    # Convert to the gray-scale
    gry = convert_to_grayscale(img)

    # Remove the lightning effect
    blr = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (125, 125), 0)
    div = cv2.divide(gry, blr, scale=192)
    ```
- 2. **Displaying Features of the image:** Then we load the non-illuminated image, convert it to gray-scale, apply Gaussian Smoothing to get the features of the image:

  - [image]
  - ```py
    # Load non-lightning image
    img = cv2.imread("non-lightning.png")

    # Convert to the gray-scale
    gry = convert_to_grayscale(img)

    # Remove the lightning effect
    blr = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (5, 5), 0)

    # Find canny features
    cny = cv2.Canny(blr, 50, 200)
    ```
  - Here you see only the left part of the track is partially visible. Of course, different parameters will give different results. If you will try them more unwanted features become more available.

---

- Second-method
- 1. **Color-segmentation** We will load the non-illuminated image, convert to HSV color-space and find the binary mask using [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html). Then we used the binary mask to make the track more visible.

  - [image]
  - ```py
    # Convert to HSV color-space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Perform color-segmentation to get the binary mask
    lwr = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    upr = np.array([179, 255, 194])
    msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)
    ```
- 2. **Extracting track using binary-mask:**

  - [image]
  - ```py
    # Extracting the rod using binary-mask
    krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50, 30))
    dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
    res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)
    ```

From my point of view, it is impossible to remove the background and display only visible track.